# Check for wrapped elements in JavaFX-FlowPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there an easy way to check for wrapped elements inside a FlowPane or determine the index at which the elements are wrapped?

Comment: What does "wrapped" mean?

Comment: Basically this [FlowPane-Wrapping](http://www.javafxapps.in/tutorials/flow_tile_layouts/flow.jpg)
In this image I'd need to get the bottom five elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it qualifies as "easy", but you can check the `boundsInParent` for each child and compare it to the first child. For a horizontal `FlowPane` this should work:

```
private List<Node> findWrapped(FlowPane flow) {
    List<Node> wrapped = new ArrayList<>();
    if (flow.getChildren().size() == 0) {
        return wrapped ;
    }
    double y = flow.getChildren().get(0).getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();
    for (Node child : flow.getChildren()) {
        if (child.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() >= y) {
            wrapped.add(child);
        }
    }
    return wrapped ;
}
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FlowPaneWrappedNodes extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 15; i++) {
            flow.getChildren().add(createPane(i));
        }
        Button button = new Button("Find wrapped");
        button.setOnAction(e ->
                findWrapped(flow).stream().map(Node::getId).forEach(System.out::println));
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(flow, null, null, button, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private List<Node> findWrapped(FlowPane flow) {
        List<Node> wrapped = new ArrayList<>();
        if (flow.getChildren().size() == 0) {
            return wrapped ;
        }
        double y = flow.getChildren().get(0).getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();
        for (Node child : flow.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() >= y) {
                wrapped.add(child);
            }
        }
        return wrapped ;
    }

    private Pane createPane(int id) {
        Pane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.setMinSize(50, 50);
        pane.setId("Pane "+id);

        Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(id));
        pane.getChildren().add(label);

        return pane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For a vertical flow pane, you can do something similar, comparing the `x` values of the bounds instead of the `y`.

Update:

Making this recompute automatically is a bit tricky. You basically need to observe the child list of the `FlowPane` (in case new nodes are added or removed), and then observe the bounds of each node in the flow pane. You can do this with code like this:

```
    FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();

    ListView<Node> wrappedNodeView = new ListView<>();

    ChangeListener<Bounds> boundsListener = (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> 
        wrappedNodeView.getItems().setAll(findWrapped(flow));

    flow.getChildren().addListener((Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                c.getAddedSubList().forEach(node -> node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(boundsListener));
            }
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                c.getRemoved().forEach(node -> node.boundsInParentProperty().removeListener(boundsListener));
            }
        }
        wrappedNodeView.getItems().setAll(findWrapped(flow));           
    });
```

(This creates a list view which displays all the "wrapped" nodes. You can obviously just update a list or whatever as you need.)

Here it is built into the previous SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FlowPaneWrappedNodes extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane();

        ListView<Node> wrappedNodeView = new ListView<>();

        ChangeListener<Bounds> boundsListener = (obs, oldBounds, newBounds) -> 
            wrappedNodeView.getItems().setAll(findWrapped(flow));

        flow.getChildren().addListener((Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(node -> node.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(boundsListener));
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(node -> node.boundsInParentProperty().removeListener(boundsListener));
                }
            }
            wrappedNodeView.getItems().setAll(findWrapped(flow));           
        });

        wrappedNodeView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Node>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Node item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText("");
                } else {
                    setText(item.getId());
                }
            }
        });

        Button button = new Button("Add pane");
        button.setOnAction(e ->
                flow.getChildren().add(createPane(flow.getChildren().size()+1)));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(flow, null, wrappedNodeView, button, null);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<Node> findWrapped(FlowPane flow) {
        ObservableList<Node> wrapped = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        if (flow.getChildren().size() == 0) {
            return wrapped ;
        }
        double y = flow.getChildren().get(0).getBoundsInParent().getMaxY();
        for (Node child : flow.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getBoundsInParent().getMinY() >= y) {
                wrapped.add(child);
            } 
        }
        return wrapped ;
    }

    private Pane createPane(int id) {
        Pane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.setMinSize(50, 50);
        pane.setId("Pane "+id);

        Label label = new Label(Integer.toString(id));
        pane.getChildren().add(label);

        return pane ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I apply it automatically? I'd want it to update it on resize of the FlowPane, but a widthProperty-Listener isn't working quite that good.

Another possiblity would be to tell the FlowPane to grow with a AnchorPoint at the top and not in the center and then set VGap on something like 500.

Comment: why go that long way, from off the top i would say iterate over the children, get the one with the largest side(width) and its the wrapped size, since its the largest. idk, just guessing out here.

Comment: @DmitrijD That's... a bit tricky, to get it to work under any possible changes. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Elltz Sure, there may be easier ways, though I admit I don't really understand what you are outlining there. (Why would the largest width of a node be the "wrapping width"?) Feel free to post an alternative answer if you have a simpler way of doing it.